# How to include a react library or component in an html page

Tags: reactjs

My requirement is to create a react library and use the same react component inside all my html pages.
Most of the examples online that include react component inside html have no external module used
In my case i am using socket.io, react-uuid as supporting modules for my react-component

````
    <head>
        <title>ChatApp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bot-container"></div>
        <script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   <!-- Load our React component. -->
        <style src="./bot-webclient/dist/index.css"></style>
        <script src="./bot-webclient/dist/index.js"></script>
        <script src="./chatElement.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>```

index.js and index.css are part of react library files generated using create-react-library
````